# File Display as buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I've recently started learning python and tkinter GUI so I had a couple problems that I could solve by myself but this one I can't get through.
Someone know the problem?
Once more I don't know what I am doing don't be too harsh.

This should print the text in each button when it is pressed, but when I press on it only the last name is displayed for all the buttons, when I use iteration only one button works and the rest give error : "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
row = 0
fCounter = 0
i = 0
import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('quizzes'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.db'):
                flist = \[\]
                
                resuname = (os.path.join(file))
                flist.append(resuname\[:-3\])

                fName = tk.Button(bFrame, text=flist[i], command = lambda: qScreen(flist[i]), width= 200, height=5, bg= "Pink")
                fName.grid(column=0, row = row)
                print(flist)
                
            row = row + 1
            fCounter = fCounter + 1

def qScreen(qname):
print(qname)
```

```
Sample Text
```

Comment: Please post what yo are ***actually doing***, not just your code! We can't help you if we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: This should print the text in each button when it is pressed, but when I press on it only the last name is displayed for all the buttons, when I use iteration only one button works and the rest give error : "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: You need to fix the indentation issue of your code first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create buttons for files ends with ".db", you can simplify your code as below:

```py
import os
...
i = 0  # counter of created buttons
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('quizzes'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.db'):
            fname = file[:-3]  # strip the .db extension
            fName = tk.Button(bFrame, text=fname,
                              command=lambda fname=fname: qScreen(fname),
                              width=25, height=2, bg="Pink")
            row, col = divmod(i, 5)  # five buttons per row
            fName.grid(column=col, row=row)
            i += 1

def qScreen(qname):
    print(qname)
...
```